# If else statement to check if any numbers are negative in R

Tags: r, vector

This is probably very simple, but I am not sure why it's not working.

For input vector `b`, I want to write a function which begins by checking `b` for any negative values. If there are any, then the function stops. Otherwise, it continues. What the function is doesn't matter.

Something like this:

```r
F <- function(b) {
  if (any(b) < 0) {
    warning("error")
  } else { 
    # the function I want to put in
  }
}
```

---

Edit:

The code that works is

```r
F <- function(b) {
  if (any(b < 0)) {
    stop("error")
  } else { 
    # the function I want to put in
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace `warning` with `stop` and you should be good to go.

Comment: both made it work for me thanks.